# How contribute action to compare with menu in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to contribute an action to the Compare With menu in eclipse, but I can't find the id to use for my action's `menuPath`.

1. What is the id for compare with menu?
2. How do you find other ids if you want to contribute an action to a menu item?

Comment: +1 for the second question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The menuPath for the "Compare With" is `menu:compareWithMenu?` Use Plugin Spy to find menu-IDs, it's the Shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: I've tried Shift+Alt+f2 but it doesn't pop up anything when I have a menu selected? I.e: I click to open the menu and trie the short cut. But if I DON'T click the menu I get the plugin in spy.

Comment: You have to press the short-cut, then your cursor changes, afterwards navigate via context-click to the menu and right-click. Now Plugin-Spy will open a popup with the desired information

Comment: Aha ... ok I got it to work now with but using SHIFT+F10 to open the menu!